# TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON when axios response is forwarded

Tags: node.js, axios

I have an API where I need to call another API inside the controller function. Which I do using Axios, but when I try to attach Axios's response on my original API's response, it throws this error:
`TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`.

Here's a sample code snippet

```
const userController = async (req,res)=>{

const ax = await axios.put(someURL, reqBody)

res.status(200).json(ax)

}
```

I know it's nonsensical to do something like this and I know why this error is caused but could somebody explain to me *How* it's happening in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON` is when some property in the object is repeated in another inner object.

Axios [response](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#response-schema) has these properties:

```
// `data` is the response that was provided by the server
data: {..your real json response..},
// `status` is the HTTP status code from the server response
status: 200,
// `statusText` is the HTTP status message from the server response
statusText: 'OK',
// `headers` the HTTP headers that the server responded with
headers: {},
// `config` is the config that was provided to `axios` for the request
config: {},
// `request` is the request that generated this response
request: {}
```

If you send the **entire** axios response object to be converted to json, some property in your real json response could **repeat** the name of private axios properties like: status, data config, etc

### Fix

Try with `ax.data` instead use the entire axios response `ax`

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense, the properties repeating themselves in my real response